# Deleting plugins via WordPress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

Today i was looking to delete a number of spam users off my admin dashboard in WP and searched for them but came up with blank screen. I then turned off the `define('WP_DEBUG', false)` to TRUE. I gthen tried to delete some plugins and cgot white screen so did it fia FTP but they still show up in WP plugins list. Basically im getting alot of white screen and i dont know how to fix it. Any ideas? Here are the issues i got when i turned on DEBUG:

> Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class FlexoArchives in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexo-archives-widget/flexo_archives_widget.php on line 69
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexo-archives-widget/flexo_archives_widget.php on line 801
>
> Notice: Undefined property: FlexoArchives::$OPT_YRCOUNT_STANDALONE in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexo-archives-widget/flexo_archives_widget.php on line 111
>
> Notice: Undefined property: FlexoArchives::$OPT_YRCOUNT in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexo-archives-widget/flexo_archives_widget.php on line 112
>
> Notice: Undefined property: FlexoArchives::$OPT_YRCOUNT_STANDALONE in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexo-archives-widget/flexo_archives_widget.php on line 124
>
> Notice: register_uninstall_hook was called incorrectly. Only a static class method or function can be used in an uninstall hook. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.) in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3547
>
> Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3547
>
> Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3497
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of APP_User_Profile::get_id() should be compatible with APP_Page_Template::get_id($template) in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/themes/classipress/framework/kernel/page-edit-profile.php on line 48
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method APP_Updater::init() should not be called statically in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/themes/classipress/framework/admin/updater.php on line 74
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of cp_CategoryDropdown::start_el() should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $current_object_id = 0) in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-content/themes/classipress/includes/theme-functions.php on line 1770
>
> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3495
>
> Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method APP_Updater::exclude_themes() should not be called statically in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 213
>
> Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method APP_Updater::check_updates() should not be called statically in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 213
>   Skip to main content
>
> Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method APP_Updater::display_warning() should not be called statically in /home/mutantsp/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ture to `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` It is just for debugging purpose for developers.

> I then tried to delete some plugins and got white screen so did it
>   via FTP

Because activated plugins are stroed in database, and when wordpress tried to locate that plugin and generates error. **You Should delete that plugin via Admin Section**.

This is how you can find the activated plugin in Database

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` like '%active_plugins%'
```

For users make sure you have uncheck the Membership option in `Settings > General Settings`

Also make sure you are using latest WordPress version.

Comment: Hi Jogesh_p thanks for that - the flexo archive plugin is now gone but i still have problem with other errors last night i updated languages in auto update + that could have caused issue but i found this comment: Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::Enable() should not be called statically in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 403
try this:
1. open file /wp-content/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.php
2. find line: function Enable() {
3. replace this line with: public static function Enable() {